# My app crashes when trying to load new activity page

Tags: android, onclick

The Error message is telling me that there is no onButton1Click method, but I never got this other in my previous activity while using onButton1Click, so idk what makes this scenario any different.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method onButton1Click(View) in the activity class com.example.chiozokamalu.brainnoodles.Results1 for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'homePageButton'
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2131)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: onButton1Click
            at java.lang.ClassCache.findMethodByName(ClassCache.java:247)
            at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:962)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2124)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is the Class file with the corresponding error

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;


public class Results1 extends MainActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    TextView resultView1, resultView2, resultView3, resultView4, resultView5,
            resultView6, resultView7, resultView8, resultView9, resultView10;

Button homePageButton;

String[] correctA1 = {
        "2", //Array 0
        "1.25", //Array1
        "-1 degrees Fahrenheit", //Array 2
        "1 hour", //Array 3
        "12 months", //Array 4
        "100", //Array 5
        "They weigh the same", //Array 6
        "Their",//Array 7
        "More than 20", //Array 8
        "The denser the cloud, the darker the atmosphere"// Array 9


};



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.results1);


    resultView1 = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultView1));
    resultView2 = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultView2));
    resultView3 = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultView3));
    resultView4 = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultView4));
    resultView5 = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultView5));
    resultView6 = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultView6));
    resultView7 = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultView7));
    resultView8 = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultView8));
    resultView9 = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultView9));
    resultView10 = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultView10));

    resultView1.setText("1. " +correctA1[0]);
    resultView2.setText("2. " +correctA1[1]);
    resultView3.setText("3. " +correctA1[2]);
    resultView4.setText("4. " +correctA1[3]);
    resultView5.setText("5. " +correctA1[4]);
    resultView6.setText("6. " +correctA1[5]);
    resultView7.setText("7. " +correctA1[6]);
    resultView8.setText("8. " +correctA1[7]);
    resultView9.setText("9. " +correctA1[8]);
    resultView10.setText("10. " +correctA1[9]);
}

@Override public void onClick(View v) {
    homePageButton = ((Button) findViewById(R.id.homePageButton));
    homePageButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    boolean yes1 = true;
    boolean yes2 = true;

        startActivity(new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN"));


}
}
```

Comment: rename `onClick` method to `onButton1Click` and remove `@Override` anotation. and you do not need the realization `View.OnClickListener`

Comment: @SorryForMyEnglish Ok this fixed it, if only I knew why my other Activity doesn't give any errors

Comment: I think because of other activity, you can find this code `button.setOnClickListener(this)`

Answer (score 0):

Check if your "homePageButton" has a handler defined in the XML file i.e. "android:onClick"

Comment: So either define a corresponding handler or remove that onClick

Answer (score 0):

Check your xml layout for this activity.  You may have specified `onButton1Click` as an onClick handler for a view but not implemented the method in your activity.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that without messing up. I have another activity in which I copied the same format for the button click. I never wrote onButton1Click in the Class file, but everything works normally.

Comment: Look in your Layout XML file (R.layout.results1).  Look for an `android:onClick` field.  You might be trying to assign the onClick event for a view to `onButton1Click() ` even though that method doesn't exist in your Activity.

Answer (score 0):

You have a android:onClick="onButton1Click" in your layout file(results1.xml), but you do not have a corresponding method in your java code to handle the onclick.

Modify your Results1 class code and add a method something like below:

```
public void onButton1Click(View v){
   //do something here
}
```

This should resolve your problem.